# Colorbox Rails not working properly

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, colorbox

I installed colorbox-rails gem for a Rails 4 project.

- included gem in Gemfile
- *= require colorbox-rails (css)
- //= require colorbox-rails (.js)

But when restart server it gives an error in file jquery.colorbox on this line

```
$('.' + boxElement, document).live('click', function (e) {
```

that

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).live is not a function
```

Comment: Have you confirmed that the jQuery finder actually finds the element?

Comment: jQuery's `live` was deprecated in version 1.7 and removed in 1.9, we're now at 2.1.4. Apparently the colorbox-rails gem is badly out of date. Maybe you should remove the gem and grab the latest colorbox by hand.

Comment: @Drenmi: It wouldn't matter if the element was found, you're free to `$(no_such_element).any_jQuery_function(...)` as much as you want, the matched element set may be empty but `$()`'s return value will still have all the usual jQuery functions. The problem is that `live` has been dead for a long time.

Comment: Thanks @muistooshort: Didn't know jQuery implemented a null object here.